Handling exif and metadata of server response which contains image
`
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('RESPONSE_PREVIEW_LENGTH', 1000);

class HttpErrorException extends Exception {}
class JsonDecodeException extends Exception {}

class RequestHandler
{
    private string $url;
    private array $data;
    private ?int $httpCode = null;
    private ?string $responseArray = null;

    public function __construct(string $url, array $data)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

public function makeAndDisplayRequest(): string
    {
        $curlHandle = curl_init();
        try {
            // Debug the prepared URL
            $url = $this->prepareUrl();
            $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('URL: ' . print_r($url, true)); // Log the URL and connection details
    
            // Debug the curl handle
            $this->configureCurl($curlHandle, $url);
            $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('cURL Handle: ' . base64_encode(print_r($curlHandle, true)));
    
            $this->logRequestDetails($url);
            
            // Debugging the response array from curl_exec
            $this->responseArray = curl_exec($curlHandle);
            $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('Response Array: ' . base64_encode(print_r($this->responseArray, true))); // Log the response
    
            // Check for cURL execution failure
            if ($this->responseArray === false) {
                throw new Exception('cURL execution failed: ' . curl_error($curlHandle));
            }
    
            // Get the HTTP status code
            $this->httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('HTTP Code: ' . $this->httpCode); // Log the HTTP code
    
            // Check if the response is an image (e.g., image/jpeg or image/png)
            $contentType = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
            if (preg_match('/image\/(jpeg|png)/', $contentType)) {
                // If it's an image, save the image to a file
                $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('Image Content Detected: ' . $contentType);
                $this->saveImageToFile($this->responseArray);  // Save the image to a file
                
                // Extract and save EXIF metadata from the image if available
                $this->extractAndSaveExifData($this->responseArray);
                
                return "Image content saved.";
            }
    
            // Debugging the curl errors handling
            $this->handleCurlErrors($curlHandle);
    
            // Debugging HTTP errors handling
            $this->handleHttpErrors();
    
            // Debug the processed response
            $processedResponse = $this->processResponse($this->responseArray);
            $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('Processed Response: ' . base64_encode(print_r($processedResponse, true))); // Log the processed response
    
            return $processedResponse; // Returning processed response
        } catch (HttpErrorException | JsonDecodeException | Exception $ex) {
            // Log the exception message
            $this->logToFileConnectionInfo('ERROR - ' . $ex->getMessage());
            echo "ERROR - " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            return "";
        } finally {
            curl_close($curlHandle);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Save image content to a file.
     *
     * @param string $imageData Raw binary data of the image.
     */
    private function saveImageToFile(string $imageData): void
    {
        // Define the file path where the image will be saved
        $imagePath = 'C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\testy na pátek\\image.jpg';  // Change the file name and extension as needed
        file_put_contents($imagePath, $imageData);  // Write the image data to a file
        $this->logToFileImage('Image saved to: ' . $imagePath);  // Log image save details
    }
    
    /**
 * Extract and save EXIF metadata from the image.
 *
 * @param string $imageData Raw binary data of the image.
 */
private function extractAndSaveExifData(string $imageData): void
{
    // Temporarily save the image data to a file to extract EXIF data
    $tempImagePath = 'C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\testy na pátek\\temp_image.jpg';
    file_put_contents($tempImagePath, $imageData);
    
    // Try to extract EXIF data from the image
    $exifData = @exif_read_data($tempImagePath);
    if ($exifData !== false) {
        // Extract and log EXIF data
        $this->logExifData('EXIF Data: ', $exifData);
    } else {
        $this->logToFileExif('No EXIF data found.');
    }
    
    // Try to extract IPTC data from the image (APP13 marker)
    $iptcData = @getimagesize($tempImagePath, $info);
    if (isset($info['APP13'])) {
        $this->logToFileExif('IPTC Data Found!');
        // Optionally, process the IPTC data if needed
    } else {
        $this->logToFileExif('No IPTC data found.');
    }

    // Try to extract XMP data (from APP1 marker)
    if (isset($info['APP1'])) {
        $xmpData = $info['APP1'];
        if (strpos($xmpData, 'XMP') !== false) {
            $this->logToFileExif('XMP Data Found!');
        } else {
            $this->logToFileExif('No XMP data found.');
        }
    } else {
        $this->logToFileExif('No XMP data found.');
    }

    // Check for ICC profile (APP2 marker)
    if (isset($info['APP2'])) {
        $this->logToFileExif('ICC Profile Found!');
    } else {
        $this->logToFileExif('No ICC Profile found.');
    }

    // Clean up the temporary image file
    unlink($tempImagePath);
}

/**
 * Log EXIF metadata to a separate file.
 *
 * @param string $message The message to log.
 * @param array $data The EXIF data array.
 */
private function logExifData(string $message, array $data): void
{
    // Log the initial message
    $this->logToFileExif($message);
    
    // Log all EXIF data
    $this->logToFileExif("EXIF Data: " . print_r($data, true));

    // Log specific EXIF tags in a structured way
    $this->logToFileExif("File Information:");
    $this->logToFileExif("  FileName: " . ($data['FileName'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  FileSize: " . ($data['FileSize'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  FileType: " . ($data['FileType'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  MimeType: " . ($data['MimeType'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  FileDateTime: " . (isset($data['FileDateTime']) ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['FileDateTime']) : 'Not Available'));
    
    $this->logToFileExif("Image Information:");
    $this->logToFileExif("  Width: " . ($data['COMPUTED']['Width'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  Height: " . ($data['COMPUTED']['Height'] ?? 'Not Available'));

    $this->logToFileExif("Camera Information:");
    $this->logToFileExif("  Make: " . ($data['Make'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  Model: " . ($data['Model'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  Focal Length: " . ($data['FocalLength'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  Orientation: " . ($data['Orientation'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  DateTimeOriginal: " . ($data['DateTimeOriginal'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  DateTimeDigitized: " . ($data['DateTimeDigitized'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("  LightSource: " . ($data['LightSource'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    
    // Log GPS data if available
    if (isset($data['GPSLatitude']) && isset($data['GPSLongitude'])) {
        $latitude = $this->convertGpsToDecimal($data['GPSLatitude'], $data['GPSLatitudeRef']);
        $longitude = $this->convertGpsToDecimal($data['GPSLongitude'], $data['GPSLongitudeRef']);
        $this->logToFileExif("GPS Coordinates: Latitude " . $latitude . ", Longitude " . $longitude);
        $this->logToFileExif("  LatitudeRef: " . ($data['GPSLatitudeRef'] ?? 'Not Available'));
        $this->logToFileExif("  LongitudeRef: " . ($data['GPSLongitudeRef'] ?? 'Not Available'));
        $this->logToFileExif("  Altitude: " . ($data['GPSAltitude'] ?? 'Not Available'));
        $this->logToFileExif("  AltitudeRef: " . ($data['GPSAltitudeRef'] ?? 'Not Available'));
        $this->logToFileExif("  Direction: " . ($data['GPSImgDirection'] ?? 'Not Available'));
        $this->logToFileExif("  Satellites: " . ($data['GPSSatellites'] ?? 'Not Available'));
        $this->logToFileExif("  DOP: " . ($data['GPSDOP'] ?? 'Not Available'));
    } else {
        $this->logToFileExif("GPS Coordinates: Not Available");
    }

    // Log EXIF comments and artist info
    $this->logToFileExif("EXIF Comment: " . ($data['COMMENT'][0] ?? 'Not Available'));
    $this->logToFileExif("Artist: " . ($data['Artist'] ?? 'Not Available'));

    // Log any additional EXIF data dynamically, even if you don't know the exact names of the keys
    $this->logToFileExif("Other EXIF Data:");
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // Skip common known keys to avoid duplication
        if (in_array($key, ['FileName', 'FileSize', 'FileType', 'MimeType', 'FileDateTime', 'COMMENT', 'Artist'])) {
            continue;
        }

        // Log all remaining EXIF keys and values
        $this->logToFileExif("  $key: " . (is_array($value) ? print_r($value, true) : $value));
    }
}

/**
 * Convert GPS data (Latitude/Longitude) to decimal format.
 *
 * @param array $gpsData GPS data array (e.g., [degrees, minutes, seconds]).
 * @param string $ref The direction (N/S or E/W).
 * @return float The decimal GPS coordinate.
 */
private function convertGpsToDecimal(array $gpsData, string $ref): float
{
    var_dump($gpsData); // Log the GPS data for debugging

    // Helper function to parse fraction strings like "49/1"
    // This should be moved outside of this function to avoid redeclaration issues
    if (!function_exists('parseFraction')) {
        function parseFraction($fraction) {
            // Split the string into numerator and denominator
            $parts = explode('/', $fraction);
            // Return the result of the division (if both parts exist and denominator is not zero)
            return isset($parts[0], $parts[1]) && $parts[1] != 0 ? $parts[0] / $parts[1] : 0;
        }
    }

    // Check if the GPS data is in the expected format and handle cases where some values might be missing
    if (count($gpsData) < 2) {
        // Handle the case where the data is incomplete (e.g., no latitude or longitude)
        $this->logToFileExif("Incomplete GPS data: " . print_r($gpsData, true));
        return 0.0;  // Return a default value (or handle as error)
    }

    // Convert the GPS data (latitude, longitude, altitude) from fraction arrays
    $degrees = isset($gpsData[0], $gpsData[1]) ? parseFraction($gpsData[0]) : 0;  // Avoid division by zero
    $minutes = isset($gpsData[2], $gpsData[3]) ? parseFraction($gpsData[2]) : 0;  // Avoid division by zero
    $seconds = isset($gpsData[4], $gpsData[5]) ? parseFraction($gpsData[4]) : 0;  // Avoid division by zero

    // Sum to get decimal format
    $decimal = $degrees + ($minutes / 60) + ($seconds / 3600);

    // Adjust for direction (N/S/E/W)
    if ($ref === 'S' || $ref === 'W') {
        $decimal *= -1;
    }

    return $decimal;
}

/**
 * Log EXIF metadata to a separate file.
 *
 * @param string $data The EXIF data to be logged.
 */
private function logToFileExif(string $data): void
{
    $logFile = "C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\testy na pátek\\exif_log.txt";  // Specify your EXIF metadata log file path
    $timestamp = date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]');  // Add a timestamp
    file_put_contents($logFile, $timestamp . ' ' . $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
    
    /**
     * Log connection and server response details to a file.
     *
     * @param string $data The data to be logged.
     */
    private function logToFileConnectionInfo(string $data): void
    {
        $logFile = "C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\testy na pátek\\connection_response_log.txt";  // Specify your connection and response log file path
        $timestamp = date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]');  // Add a timestamp
        file_put_contents($logFile, $timestamp . ' ' . $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
    
    /**
     * Log image-related details to a separate file.
     *
     * @param string $data The image-related data to be logged.
     */
    private function logToFileImage(string $data): void
    {
        $logFile = "C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\testy na pátek\\image_log.txt";  // Specify your image log file path
        $timestamp = date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]');  // Add a timestamp
        file_put_contents($logFile, $timestamp . ' ' . $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
`

This code is made to post curl request and work with data recieved as response.
Because the response contains image and many other data then I have decided to separate outputs.
Currently I am getting:

[2024-11-08 13:34:40] EXIF Data:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] EXIF Data: Array
(
[FileName] => temp_image.jpg
[FileDateTime] => 1731069280
[FileSize] => 174745
[FileType] => 2
[MimeType] => image/jpeg
[SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, COMMENT, EXIF, GPS
[COMPUTED] => Array
(
[html] => width="1200" height="900"
[Height] => 900
[Width] => 1200
[IsColor] => 1
[ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
)
[Artist] => c076e10a-f802-4072-abe8-e1d7fd4079d5
[ImageWidth] => 4000
[Model] => SM-A336B
[ImageLength] => 3000
[Make] => samsung
[Orientation] => 6
[DateTime] => 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 196
[GPS_IFD_Pointer] => 298
[COMMENT] => Array
(
[0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality
    )

[DateTimeOriginal] => 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[DateTimeDigitized] => 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[FocalLength] => 93/20
[LightSource] => 0
[GPSLatitude] => Array
(
[0] => 49/1
[1] => 12/1
[2] => 8602/223
)
[GPSAltitude] => 1453/5
[GPSLatitudeRef] => N
[GPSAltitudeRef] =>
[GPSLongitudeRef] => E
[GPSSatellites] => {"totalCount":"0","usedCount":"0"}
[GPSLongitude] => Array
(
[0] => 16/1
[1] => 35/1
[2] => 6038/185
)
[GPSImgDirection] => 187091/555
[GPSDOP] => 7/5
[GPSImgDirectionRef] => M
)
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] File Information:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   FileName: temp_image.jpg
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   FileSize: 174745
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   FileType: 2
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   MimeType: image/jpeg
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   FileDateTime: 2024-11-08 13:34:40
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] Image Information:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Width: 1200
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Height: 900
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] Camera Information:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Make: samsung
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Model: SM-A336B
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Focal Length: 93/20
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Orientation: 6
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   DateTimeOriginal: 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   DateTimeDigitized: 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   LightSource: 0
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] GPS Coordinates: Latitude 49, Longitude 16
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   LatitudeRef: N
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   LongitudeRef: E
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Altitude: 1453/5
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   AltitudeRef:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Direction: 187091/555
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Satellites: {"totalCount":"0","usedCount":"0"}
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   DOP: 7/5
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] EXIF Comment: CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] Artist: c076e10a-f802-4072-abe8-e1d7fd4079d5
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] Other EXIF Data:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, COMMENT, EXIF, GPS
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   COMPUTED: Array
(
[html] => width="1200" height="900"
[Height] => 900
[Width] => 1200
[IsColor] => 1
[ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
)
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   ImageWidth: 4000
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Model: SM-A336B
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   ImageLength: 3000
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Make: samsung
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Orientation: 6
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   DateTime: 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   Exif_IFD_Pointer: 196
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPS_IFD_Pointer: 298
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   DateTimeOriginal: 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   DateTimeDigitized: 2024:10:11 08:02:04
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   FocalLength: 93/20
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   LightSource: 0
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSLatitude: Array
(
[0] => 49/1
[1] => 12/1
[2] => 8602/223
)
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSAltitude: 1453/5
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSLatitudeRef: N
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSAltitudeRef:
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSLongitudeRef: E
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSSatellites: {"totalCount":"0","usedCount":"0"}
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSLongitude: Array
(
[0] => 16/1
[1] => 35/1
[2] => 6038/185
)
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSImgDirection: 187091/555
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSDOP: 7/5
[2024-11-08 13:34:40]   GPSImgDirectionRef: M
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] No IPTC data found.
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] No XMP data found.
[2024-11-08 13:34:40] ICC Profile Found!

But I am absolutely sure those data are not all, but still I am not sure how to fetch them all. What to do to ensure I have got every detail possible, if I need to even improve curl request handling or image + response encoding.
link to response array .txt file: https://file.io/h2COV3XQaGSk
I tryed to utilise curl + response separation which seems to be almostly fine, but still I need to ensure I didn't miss any detail for server, interface and image file testing where I need to ensure that everything works as it should and if not I will get error response or exception.

This is very sloppy in both using Stack Overflow formatting and "recognizing" metadata. The JFIF segments APP2 and APP13 can contain other metadata, not only ICC and IPTC. Likewise the file formats themselves can have various other metadata. You "simply" have to learn to not rely on PHP's exif_read_data() alone, but instead being able to parse each file format to spot addtional metadata.
